# Cyrillic letters don't store fine with Glassfish and Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, character-encoding, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 4.0, JSF 2.2.5, MySQL 5.5 and J Conn 5.1.29. When I enter some Cyrillic letters in a form, they are saved as "ÑÐ´ÑÐ´ÑÑÐ´Ñ" in the database. I have also noticed that if the validation fails in the form, the existing Cyrillic letters in the form are modified to "ÑÐ´ÑÐ´ÑÑÐ´Ñ".

It is working right if I saved them through MySQL Workbench, and they are displayed fine on the web page.

The JSF page is set to UFT-8.

MySQL:

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci' 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8' 
character-set-server=utf8 
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci 
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved when I added the following to the `glassfish-web.xml`

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset=”UTF-8″/>
```