# GlassFish + MySQL + XHTML + Java Beans + UTF-8 issue

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, utf-8, glassfish

Hello,

I developed a JSF2.2 web app in NetBeans 7.4. It worked great on Apache Tomcat 7.0.50. But now I switched to GlassFish 4 and I have a problem with some Serbian characters (**Ć, Č, Š, Đ, Ž**...)

MySQL database has **utf8_general_ci** collation, as well as all the tables and every varchar column.

**Connection URL:**

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

**web.xml** has the following part:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>PARAMETER_ENCODING</param-name>
<param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**supporters.xhtml** file where I display the table content:

```
<h:dataTable id="listSupportersTable" value="#{supportersBean.list}"...>
...
<h:outputText value="#{row.name}"/>
...
</h:dataTable>
```

In **SupportersBean.java** I generate a list and for debugging purposes I print the result:

```
...
while (resultSet.next()) {
supporter.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name") + ", " + supporter.getName());
list.add(supporter)
}
...
```

For testing purposes, I made one entry in the table, **name=Ć** (and it displays correctly in MySQL). On the supporters.xhtml page, the name is also **Ć**, but the println gives: **Ä†, Ä†**

For editing the entry, I created a commandLink on the supporters.xhtml page, with action:

```
action="#{supportersBean.editSelected(event)}"
```

...and I gave it a parameter:

```
<f:param name="supportersName" value="#{row.name}"/>
```

Here's the **editSelected** procedure:

```
public String editSelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
newName=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("supportersName");
System.out.println("newName="+newName); // for debugging
isEditing = true;
return "editSupporters.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The println gives me: newName=**Ã„Â†**

The **editSupporters.xhtml** part:

```
<h:inputText value="#{supportersBean.newName}"/>
```

In this field I see the character **Ä**. I don't change anything here, I only click the Save button, which does the following:

```
supporter.setName(newName);
System.out.println("Updated: "+newName);
dao.update(supporter);
```

The println gives: Updated: **ÃƒÂ„Ã‚Â†**

After this, the outputField on my supporters.xhtml page has the value **ÃÂ**. If I click Edit again, the inputText field will have the value: **ÃÂÃÂ**, and when I click Save, the outputField will be **ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ**...

Finally, after those two edit/saves, I check my table via phpMyAdmin. The value in the column is: **ÃÂ**

Does anyone has any idea what the problem could be???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22614044/1168874

I should add this to the glassfish-web.xml file:

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```

The println's in Java still give me some weird characters, but it doesn't matter as long as the database content is correct and the web page display is fine.

All the credits for this solution go to [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747052/pavel)